# Get max date in each 'block' of data

Tags: sql-server

I have a table that looks something like this (when ordered by `PersonID, Date`):

```
 PersonID | Stage       | Date
----------|-------------|------------
 12       | Start       | 01 Jan 2010
 12       | Step 1      | 03 Jan 2010
 12       | Step 2      | 05 Jan 2010
 12       | Start       | 06 Jan 2010
 12       | Step 1      | 07 Jan 2010
 12       | Start       | 09 Jan 2010
 ...
```

`Stage` essentially breaks activity into blocks - the first three records is one block of activity, the next two is another stage, etc. Every block begins with `Start`, but there's no defined end (eg the first block ends `Step 2`, the second ends `Step 1`, the third one might end `Step 47` or `Turnips` or something):

```
Block 1:
 PersonID | Stage       | Date
----------|-------------|------------
 12       | Start       | 01 Jan 2010
 12       | Step 1      | 03 Jan 2010
 12       | Step 2      | 05 Jan 2010

Block 2:
 PersonID | Stage       | Date
----------|-------------|------------
 12       | Start       | 06 Jan 2010
 12       | Step 1      | 07 Jan 2010
```

I need to query the max date for each block (eg 'block 1' is 05 Jan 2010, 'block 2' is 07 Jan 2010), but I'm not sure how to achieve this:

```
select
     PersonID
    ,max(Date)
from
    MyTable -- subquery / cte required?

group by
    PersonID
```

I don't really even have a start on this one - I suspect I'll need a subquery/CTE to define the blocks somehow first, or maybe I can do something with `row_number() over (partition by ...)`?

Comment: Just add Stage to your list of columns and the group by.

Comment: So a "block" is everything from 'Start' until the next 'Start'?

Comment: @SeanLange That won't work. Then I'll get the max Date of all the `Start` stages, the max date of all the `Step 1` stages, etc. I want the max (last) date of each block starting `Start` and ending on the record before the next start

Comment: @Andrew Yes, although note that the final block will not have a 'next `Start`'

Answer (score 1):

I put data into `OUTER APPLY`

```
DECLARE @table TABLE (PersonID INT, Stage VARCHAR(100), Date DateTime2)

INSERT INTO @table SELECT  12, 'Start', '2010-01-01'
INSERT INTO @table SELECT  12, 'Step 1', '2010-01-03'
INSERT INTO @table SELECT  12, 'Step 2', '2010-01-05'
INSERT INTO @table SELECT  12, 'Start', '2010-01-06'
INSERT INTO @table SELECT  12, 'Step 1', '2010-01-07'
INSERT INTO @table SELECT  12, 'Start', '2010-01-09'
INSERT INTO @table SELECT  13, 'Start', '2010-01-01'
INSERT INTO @table SELECT  13, 'Step 1', '2010-01-03'
INSERT INTO @table SELECT  13, 'Step 2', '2010-01-05'
INSERT INTO @table SELECT  13, 'Start', '2010-01-06'
INSERT INTO @table SELECT  13, 'Step 1', '2010-01-07'
INSERT INTO @table SELECT  13, 'Start', '2010-01-09'

;WITH StartTable AS (

    SELECT PersonID, Stage, [Date], ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY PersonID, Date) AS ROWID
    FROM @table
    WHERE Stage = 'Start'

)
SELECT PersonID, T2.MaxDate
FROM StartTable ST1
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT MAX(TB.Date) AS MaxDate
    FROM StartTable ST2
    INNER JOIN @table TB 
        ON TB.PersonID = ST2.PersonID
        AND TB.Date < ST2.Date
    WHERE ST1.ROWID + 1 = ST2.ROWID
        AND ST1.PersonID = ST2.PersonID
    GROUP BY TB.PersonID
) AS T2
```

OR can be logic made like this:

```
SELECT T1.PersonID, (
        SELECT MAX([Date])
        FROM @table T2 -- gives MAX date in stage
        WHERE T2.Stage != 'Start' AND T2.PersonID = T1.PersonID
            AND [Date] < (SELECT MIN(Date) FROM @table T3 WHERE T3.Stage = 'Start' AND T3.Date > T1.Date AND T3.PersonID = T1.PersonID) -- gives next date for starting stage
) 
FROM @table T1
WHERE Stage = 'Start'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will at least be a good start:
[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/53e0b/4)

```
with RNs as (
select
personid,
stage,
row_number() over (order by personid,[date]) as RN,
[date]
from
table1
) ,
Starts as (
select
personid,
stage,
rn,
[date]
from
  RNs
where
Stage = 'Start')

select
RNs.PersonId,
RNs.Stage,
RNs.[Date]
from
RNs
inner join starts
  on RNs.rn = starts.rn - 1
```

Basically, this should get you the row prior to each 'Start' row (based on sorting by personid and your date column).

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% clear on what you want but this will get the PersonID, max Date and StageNumber for each "grouping". Please note I changed it to MyDate to avoid naming issues. I would suggest that you normalize this data into at least a couple tables so you don't have to wrestle with multiple row "types" in the same table.

```
declare @Something table
(
    PersonID int,
    Stage varchar(10),
    MyDate date
);

insert @Something
select 12, 'Start', '01 Jan 2010' union all
select 12, 'Step 1', '03 Jan 2010' union all
select 12, 'Step 2', '05 Jan 2010' union all
select 12, 'Start', '06 Jan 2010' union all
select 12, 'Step 1', '07 Jan 2010' union all
select 12, 'Start', '09 Jan 2010';

with MyOrderedData as
(
    select PersonID
        , MyDate
        , ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by Stage order by MyDate) as Stage
    from @Something
)

select PersonID, MAX(MyDate), Stage
from MyOrderedData
group by PersonID, Stage
order by Stage;
```